# Nodejs Crypto decrypt fails after one successful encryption and decryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I got a weird scenario on nodejs where crypto works encryption and decryption of text only once when i load the node server. After the second try it encrypts the text fine but is unable to decrypt the text on second try.

This is my code:

```
function Encrypt(mytext) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc','fa97be5d286a67114cf74acf46d179725581d562');
  var crypted = cipher.update(mytext,'utf8','hex');
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
}

function Decipher(mytext) {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-  cbc','fa97be5d286a67114cf74acf46d179725581d562');
  var dec = decipher.update(mytext,'hex','utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
}
```

This works fine ONCE the nodejs server loads, encrypt and decrypts the data perfectly, the second time this function is used elsewhere with a different text or key it fails to decrypt the text. I'm puzzled.

Comment: I don't think passing crypted in as it is appended to will work, but I haven't tried it.  I suspect the text you are passing in to decipher is incorrect.

Comment: can you post, the part of the code in which you call your functions ? also add `console.log` at the end of the functions, and try using `return` to get the value ..

Comment: It fails to decrypt the text is not really helpful error description. What *does* it do?

Comment: This is not the first time you've posted questions and ignored any comments. If you don't care about the comments, please refrain from posting to this site.

Comment: I've managed to resolve this successfully, what happened is that the template object i loaded into memory got encrypted and stayed there. The second round the object itself loaded encrypted already. It wasn't an encryption issue but an object not being initialised properly. Once i initialised the object as a new instance it encrypted only that object and not the master one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved after i've added:

delete require.cache[require.resolve('./templates/prd')];

The required object stayed in cache and continued to be encrypted over and over. once i cleared the cache everytime i loaded the template it started encrypting it properly.